# Yolov7 using OpenCV 4.6.0 dnn

Tags: c++, opencv, yolo, yolov5

I was trying to load yolov7-nms-640.onnx downloaded from YOLOv7 official repo (https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/) using OpenCV dnn module. But I got an error message

```
OpenCV(4.6.0) Error: Unspecified error (> Node [NonMaxSuppression@ai.onnx]:(onnx_node!NonMaxSuppression_430) parse error: OpenCV(4.6.0) c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\dnn\src\layer_internals.hpp:110: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Can't create layer "onnx_node!NonMaxSuppression_430" of type "NonMaxSuppression" in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::detail::LayerData::getLayerInstance'
> ) in cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::ONNXImporter::handleNode, file c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\dnn\src\onnx\onnx_importer.cpp, line 1040.
```

Can I load Yolov7 using OpenCV?

Comment: WIP: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/22473

Comment: how did you implement in C++ because it is implemented in python

Answer (score 0):

You can't use YOLOv7 with 'NMS processing inside de model' but, you can use YOLOv7 and do postprocessing for getting the final boxes.